# Is it possible to limit iterations (b.N) in Go Benchmarking?

Tags: go

I'm trying to benchmark an operation which requires expensive preparation which I'm excluding using StopTimer() and StartTimer(). Specifically, I'm benchmarking nth-item insertion into a sorted list.

Sample code:

```
n := 100

// Run the process b.N times
for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {

    // Stop the timer for our expensive preparation work (inserting n-1 items)
    b.StopTimer()

    // ...

    // Insert n-1 items
    for j := 1; j < n; j++ {
        m.InsertItem(o)
    }

    // ...

    // Resume the timer
    b.StartTimer()

    // Insert the nth item
    m.InsertItem(o)

}
```

The problem is that Go's benchmarking heuristic is limiting b.N according to the benchmarked time, not the total time. It ends up asking for 5MM (5000000) iterations of 100th order insertion, and this takes more time than is reasonable (I want to benchmark up to the 10 millionth item insertion).

Is there a way to specify a maximum b.N for a specific benchmark in Go's benchmark tool? I did not find anything in the docs myself.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Setting an explicit iteration count (100 times):

```
go test -bench=. -benchtime=100x
```

---

Specify the time (10 seconds):

```
go test -bench=. -benchtime=10s
```

---

To limit iterations (`b.N`) in Go Benchmarking:
Since [Go 1.12](https://golang.org/doc/go1.12#testing):

> The `-benchtime` flag now supports setting an explicit iteration count instead of a time when the value ends with an "x". For example, `-benchtime=100x` runs the benchmark 100 times.

Answer (score 6):

`-benchtime` flag can be used to specify the time for which you want to run the benchmark([source](https://grokbase.com/t/gg/golang-nuts/133pfm5wzw/go-nuts-increasing-benchmark-time)). Although I haven't tried it, providing a lower value of time than 1 sec should do the trick.

`go test -bench=. -benchtime=10s`

Comment: I was hopeful about this one, but it looks like that's actually a minimum time to hit (according to the [docs re: benchmark flag: "Run enough iterations of each benchmark to take t".

Even worse for my case, I tried it out and it looks like it's trying to hit that minimum run time based on measured benchmark time, not total execution time. So it's taking even longer.

Thanks for the suggestion, though, it was the right idea!

  https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Testing_flags

Comment: Actually, I tested this further and it appears that -benchtime does behave as a target, not just a min or max. Since the per op measured execution time for my case is around 300ns, I set benchtime to 1ms and it worked reasonably well. It's a blunt instrument since you can't set benchtime per benchmark, but it gets the job done. Thank you Saty!